# Using Generics properties with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, entity-framework-4, metadata

I know that [EF isn't supposed to support generic Entity types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541154/how-to-create-an-entity-data-model-for-inherited-generic-types) but I have a huge need for it in a project...
I have about 200 classes containing 0 to 5 complex generic property :

```
public class MyCommonProperty
{
    public virtual string Key { get; set; }
}

public class MyCustomClass<T> : MyCommonProperty where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    public virtual T Value { get; set; }
    public virtual string DisplayValue { get; set; }

    public MyCustomClass(string key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }
}

public class ConcreteClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public MyCustomClass<CustomType1> CustomType1 { get; set; }
    public MyCustomClass<CustomType2> CustomType2 { get; set; }
}
```

I just want to persist the *Key* property in the DB with Entity Frameworks, using these POCO.
Here is my model :

- Entity Type

  - **ConcreteClass**

    - Id (*int*, Identity)
    - CustomType1 (*MyCommonProperty*)
    - CustomType2 (*MyCommonProperty*)
- Complex Types

  - **MyCommonProperty**

    - Key (*string*)

Finally, in my UI, the code looks like :

```
using (var db = new ModelContainer())
{
    db.ConcreteClassSet.AddObject(new ConcreteClass()
    {
        CustomType1 = new MyCustomClass<CustomType1>() { Key = "RandomKey1" },
        CustomType2 = new MyCustomClass<CustomType2>() { Key = "RandomKey2" }
    });
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I run this code, I get this error :

> The member with identity
>   'Domain.MyCustomClass`1[[Domain.CustomType1, Domain,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' does not
>   exist in the metadata collection.

Although *MyCustomClass* wasn't defined in my edmx, I though EF wouldn't care about this class as a *MyCustomClass* is also a *MyCommonProperty* wich is defined in the metadata...

I overrided the *ValidateEntity* in my container :

```
public partial class ModelContainer : DbContext
{
    public ModelContainer()
        : base("name=ModelContainer")
    {
    }

    protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
    {
        if (entityEntry.Entity is ConcreteClass)
            return new DbEntityValidationResult(entityEntry, new List<DbValidationError>());
        return base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);
    }

    public DbSet<ConcreteClass> ConcreteClassSet { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, I turned off the validation for my *ConcreteClass*, telling EF that they are always valid.
With this workaround, the *db.Save()* works : in the database, a new row is added, with a generated Id and "RandomKey1" and "RandomKey2" in the *CustomType1* and *CustomType2* fields.

Now the problem is the validation : I don't want to turn off the validation for all the entities containing those generics properties
It looks like the only problem is that Entity search for the concrete type (*MyCustomClass*) of my property in the metadata and can't find it because the only type declared there is *MyCommonProperty*

I think that it would be possible by modifying the metadata to add some fake types into it.
For example by finding the *MyCommonProperty*, copying it, and rename the copy *'Domain.MyCustomClass`1[[Domain.CustomType1, Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'*

```
var metadata = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
var metaType = metadata.GetType("MyCommonProperty", "Domain", DataSpace.CSpace);
metaType.Name = "'Domain.MyCustomClass`1[[Domain.CustomType1, Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'";
metadata.RegisterItemCollection(metaType);
```

I couldn't find a way to make it (lacks of knowledge and skill) so if someone have an idea or some hints, I would be grateful.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94778/Repository-and-Unit-of-Work-T4-Template-for-Entity. You could possibly approach this using t4 templating to generate contexts/repositories etc. rather than having making a single generic repository (although if you look at the generated classes on that page, there are some generic methods). This removes some of the tedium when you have lots of entity types. You can create generated classes as `partial` so you can add additional functionality in another partial class without directly modifying the generated code.

Comment: I cannot use T4 to generate my classes as they are located in a separated assembly, and maintained by another team : the edmx and the DbContext is in a DAL namespace and solution, and the POCO are in a Domain namespace and solution.
And I don't want to have generics methods but generics properties with getter and setter, to avoid duplicating and then maintaining the same code (about 100 lines) in nearly 500 properties...

The only problem is to find a way to copy then rename an entry in the **ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace**

Comment: You don't actually need an EDMX to use t4 templating (see the Tutorial section of http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/). I did just come across another approach which used reflection to late bind to the EDM (definitely looks like it is worth a read) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348335/connect-to-an-entity-model-using-reflection. This also seems like a candidate for contextual binding with dependency injection (something like this https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding), but I'll need to have a bit more of a think about that.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you are suggesting to build a T4 template in my Domain solution, use it to parse the DAL edmx (actually xml) file to find all types declared (no classes are generated there because I use POCO : no reflection possible), then generate a lot of partial classes
I have 2 problems with this solution : 
- I won't be able to add comments on my classes and their properties or those comments will be wiped each time the T4 is run
- All classes will be generated in a single namespace but I need them to be located in different namespaces, subnamespaces, according to some Business logic

Comment: `Unless I'm mistaken, you are suggesting to build a T4 template in my Domain solution, use it to parse the DAL edmx (actually xml) file to find all types declared` t4 may be unsuitable, but in that last comment I was just pointing out that you don't need have an EDMX to use t4. Seperately I'm suggesting you look into this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2350243/201648. `All classes will be generated in a single namespace but I need them to be located in different namespaces, subnamespaces, according to some Business logic` see my previous comment about contextual-binding with Ninject.

Comment: Just with regard to your other comment `I won't be able to add comments on my classes and their properties or those comments will be wiped each time the T4 is run` that isn't strictly true if you write your template correctly. Search this page - http://tdryan.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/another-entity-framework-4-repository_5988.html - for `bool forceCodeGeneration = false;`. So you could keep your comments etc. but use automatically generated classes. I still don't have a neat solution the namespaces issues.